# Page not found in Vite-plugin-page

Tags: vuejs3, vite, vite-plugin-pages

I'm using Vite-plugin-page for setting my Vue.js routing system. In this plugin, apparently, setting up not found page is not provided.

For this purpose, I created a file named 404.vue in page directory, But, when inserting wrong URL, the page does not redirect to 404.vue page.
How can handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In vite-plugin-pages to create 404 page you can create [...all].vue file in your page directory.

[...all].vue

Read Catch-all Routes in vite-plugin-pages.